# Can I have 2 villager-based farms close to each other?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Many [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BhlLIIpRh4&t=361s) say not to build 2 farms involving villagers less than 100 blocks away. As far as I can tell, this is because villagers might link to other beds and workstations. If all of the villagers in one farm are linked to beds and workstations, and I build another farm near it, will everything work correctly? The first farm is an iron farm, and the second will be a wheat farm.